# consume web service in xamarin.forms json

Tags: c#, json, xaml, xamarin.forms

I want to display the value of the source to the List view on the button Name and Image Logo as I as result I have bind the Image source and Name. However there seems to be no results displayed.

```
public async Task<string> GetRequest (string url){
    Uri geturi = new Uri("http://172.20.129.193/nypstudentlifeservice/"); 
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage responseGet = await client.GetAsync(geturi);
    return responseGet.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<CsClubList>> getClubList()
{
    string result = await GetRequest("api/club/list?categoryid=2");

    CsClubList[] clublist = null;

    var clubtoken = JObject.Parse(result)[0];

    clublist = clubtoken.Select(clublists => new CsClubList()
    {
        Id = (int)clublists["Id"],
        Name = (string)clublists["Name"],
        Logo = (string)clublists["Logo"],
        CategoryId = (int)clublists["CategoryId"]
    }).ToArray();

    return clublist;
}
```

This are the codes that I did to try to consume the Json web service.

This is the class file of the `CsClubList`

```
public class CsClubList
{
    public int Id{ get; set;}
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Logo {get; set;}
}
```

For the xaml.cs file

```
public partial class ListClubs : ContentPage
{
    private IEnumerable<CsClubList> _ClubList;

    public ListClubs ()
    {
         InitializeComponent();
         setClubs(Clublistview); //The statement is not awaited and execution of current method continues before the call is complete. Consider using 'await' operator or calling 'Wait' method
    }


    public IEnumerable<CsClubList> ClubList 
    {
        get { return _ClubList; }
        set { _ClubList = value; }
    }

    private async void setClubs(ListView listview)
    {
        ClubApiClient service = new ClubApiClient();
        var clublist = await service.getClubList();
        listview.ItemsSource = clublist.ToList();
    }
}
```

This is the xaml page:

```
<ListView  x:Name="Clublistview">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White"
                    Orientation="Vertical">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Logo}" IsVisible="true" WidthRequest="42" HeightRequest="42"/>
                             <Button Text="{Binding Name}" x:Name="BtnClub" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="100, 25, 100, 25" Clicked="OnListClubsClicked" TextColor="Black" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

this is the link for the Json web service:

http://172.20.129.193/nypstudentlifeservice/api/club/list?categoryid=2

```
[{"Id":21,"CategoryId":2,"Name":"Chinese Cultural Group","Logo":"http://www.nyp.edu.sg/web/campus_life/cca/arts_&_culture/image/CCG2.png"},{"Id":22,"CategoryId":2,"Name":"Chinese Orchestra","Logo":"http://www.nyp.edu.sg/web/campus_life/cca/arts_&_culture/image/CO-ICON.png"},{"Id":23,"CategoryId":2,"Name":"Dance Company","Logo":"http://www.nyp.edu.sg/web/campus_life/cca/arts_&_culture/image/DC2.png"},{"Id":24,"CategoryId":2,"Name":"Danz Inc.","Logo":"http://www.nyp.edu.sg/web/campus_life/cca/arts_&_culture/image/DI-ICON.png"},{"Id":25,"CategoryId":2,"Name":"Der Treff German Club","Logo":"http://www.nyp.edu.sg/web/campus_life/cca/arts_&_culture/image/DTG-ICON.png"},{"Id":26,"CategoryId":2,"Name":"Foreign Bodies Dance Group","Logo":"http://www.nyp.edu.sg/web/campus_life/cca/arts_&_culture/image/FB-ICON.png"}]
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I want to display the value of the source to the List view on the button Name and Image Logo as I as result I have bind the Image source and Name. However there seems to be no results displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't really stated what the problem is or what is your question, but here are some observations based on the code you provided.

You are mixing async and synchronous calls in your code. Don't use `.Result` or `.Wait` in an async method.

Remove `.Result` from the line where you are trying to read the response as string and `await` the result just as you did with the HTTP request.

Also noticed that you were not constructing the Uri for your request properly. You created a Uri with the base address but did not include the url parameter provided.

```
public async Task<string> GetRequest(string url) {
    Uri getUri = new Uri("http://172.20.129.193/nypstudentlifeservice/" + url);
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage responseGet = await client.GetAsync(getUri);
    responseGet.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); // Throw if not a success code.
    string content = await responseGet.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return content;
}

public async Task<IEnumerable<CsClubList>> getClubList() {
    string json = await GetRequest("api/club/list?categoryid=2");

    List<CsClubList> clublist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CsClubList>>(json);

    return clublist;
}
```

You should also where possible using async on void methods unless they are event handlers.

So if possible you need to change this

```
//NO NO NO NO NO
private async void setClubs(ListView listview)
{
    ClubApiClient service = new ClubApiClient();
    var clublist = await service.getClubList();
    listview.ItemsSource = clublist.ToList();
}
```

To this

```
private async Task setClubs(ListView listview)
{
    ClubApiClient service = new ClubApiClient();
    var clublist = await service.getClubList();
    listview.ItemsSource = clublist.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the response! However, I still face some problems displaying the values onto the Image and Button on my xaml page.

Comment: Well given that you have not stated any of that in you question there was no way for me to knwo that that was your problem. Edit your question with proper details so that the community can provide you with better answers.

Comment: Hi my apologises for not stating is just now. I've just updated the question.

Comment: You still haven't asked a question. You have just provided your code and left it to the community to guess what the problem is. Clearly state what the problem is and what you have tried so far to fix it.

Comment: Hi thank you for mentioning, I've just updated my question hope that it would be sufficient.

Comment: Does the link you provided work when you browse to it?

Comment: Hi yes! the Json link I provided works when I browse it.

Comment: Ok adding the json to the question helps as it does not work form here. IP is probably internal.

Comment: Try debugging with the suggested changes and see if the `setClubs` method is executing properly.

Comment: Hi the method does not seems to cause any errors. However, it does not display the results.

Comment: Put break points in the different methods and make sure data is being return and passed to the list.

Comment: Hi there is a message however stating: "The statement is not awaited and execution of current method continues before the call is complete. Consider using 'await' operator or calling 'wait' method.

Comment: Add a handler for the onload of the page and move the `setClubs` to there where you can properly async and await it. You wont be able to do it in the constructor like you have it now

Comment: Is it possible for you to elaborate your answer as I don't quite get it?

Comment: Ok. try using `Task.Run(() => setClubs(Clublistview));` in the constructor.

Comment: Hi I've just tried that method however there are still no results on the list view.

Comment: Again I ask are the breakpoints being hit and data being seen in the variables while debugging?

Comment: Hi this time there are no breakpoints being hit. I am still unable to view the data in the list view

Comment: Ok here is my advice. Debug the code and make sure that the methods are being called and that data is being returned even before assigning it to the list view. There not much more I can do for you from here.